# my display() is not running or showing my println

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, println

The program I am working on currently runs successfully but it doesn't execute part of my program and it shows no errors.

The prompt was: 
"Create an application that declares a Purchase object and prompts the user for purchase details. When you prompt for an invoice number, do not let the user proceed until a number between 1000 and 8000 has been entered. When you prompt for a sale amount, do not proceed until the user has entered a non-negative number, sale amount, and sales tax. Save the file as `CreatePurchase.java.`"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class CreatePurchase {
    static int invoiceNum; // I made these variables static because
    static double amount; // it fixed an error I was having with using
                            // non-static variables in a static field?

    double tax = .05;
    double totalamount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Purchase completedPurchase = new Purchase();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Please enter the invoice number! (Must be between 1000 and 8000!)");
        invoiceNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out
                .println("Please enter the amount of the sale! (Must be greater than 0!)");
        amount = input.nextDouble();

        while (invoiceNum < 1000 || invoiceNum > 8000) {
            System.out
                    .println("The invoice number you entered is invalid, try again!");
        }
        while (amount < 0) {
            System.out.println("The sale amount is invalid, try again!");
        }
    }

    public int getInvoiceNum(int invoiceNum) {
        return invoiceNum;
    }

    public double getAmount(double amount) {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getTotalAmount(double totalAmount) {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(double tax, double amount) {
        double totalAmount = (amount * tax);
    }

    public void display(int invoiceNum, double amount, double totalAmount) {
        System.out.println("Your invoice number is:" + invoiceNum + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount is: " + amount + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount after tax is: " + totalAmount
                + ".");
    }
}
```

I have spent hours trying to figure out what I need to fix in order to get my display method to work. The program runs successfully, and there are no errors, so I am not sure what to even try to fix. 
(Sorry if my code or question doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Besides the mentioned direct problem, you have a couple of dangerous conditions lurking in your code.  Take a look again - what happens if you put in a negative amount? Try if you feel daring.  The reason the compiler was complaining about "static can't access non-static variables" is because the professor probably expects you to create a `Purchase` object (read the problem statement again!), and modify the values in that (eg, via `completedPurchase.tax = .2`).  Generally speaking, mutable `static` variables should be avoided.  After you get this working, go over to [codereview.se] for more.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone that replied, you were all very helpful and thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would massively refactor your code if given the chance.  First, the `CreatePurchase` class should be a simply POJO (plain old Java object), containing state for the invoice number, purchase amount, and sales tax, along with getter and setter methods for accessing and changing that state.  Next, the `main()` method within this class will instantiate a `CreatePurchase` object for storing the user input.  A big change I made was in how the code handles user inputs.  My code below uses two `while` loops to poll the user for a correct invoice number (between `1000` and `8000`) and amount (non negative), and only then proceeds with the remainder of the method.  Finally, the `CreatePurchase` object created is used to output the result to the console.

```
public final class CreatePurchase {
    private int invoiceNum;
    private double amount;
    private double totalamount;

    // I am hard-coding the sales tax as 5%, as you did in your question,
    // though this code can easily be modified if you also want to input the tax
    private final double tax = .05;

    public int getInvoiceNum() {
        return invoiceNum;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNum(int invoiceNum) {
        this.invoiceNum = invoiceNum;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(double totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreatePurchase cp = new CreatePurchase();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // these next two do-while loops will continue polling the user
        // until he enters a valid input
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the invoice number! (Must be between 1000 and 8000!)");
            invoiceNum = input.nextInt();
        } while (invoiceNum < 1000 || invoiceNum > 8000);

        cp.setInvoiceNum(invoiceNum);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the amount of the sale! (Must be greater than 0!)");
            amount = input.nextDouble();
        } while (amount < 0);

        totalamount = amount*(1 + tax);
        cp.setAmount(amount);
        cp.setTotalAmount(totalAmount);

        // now use the CreatePurchase object to print out
        // details of the transaction
        System.out.println("Your invoice number is:" + cp.getInvoiceNum() + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount is: " + cp.getAmount() + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount after tax is: " + cp.getTotalAmount() + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax error - you use `totalamount` and `tax`, but those are still instance variables.

Comment: I didn't vote (down or otherwise) on your answer.  If you're going to give them complete code, could you at least walk through the changes?

Comment: Any comment for the downvote?  My answer seems to be precisely what the OP asks for.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through these changes, I was a really confused at first, but now I understand a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You declared method `public void display(int invoiceNum, double amount, double totalAmount)` but you never actually used it.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Believe it or not, it doesn't fully answer the OP, because it has an infinite `while` loop which will never break in the case of a wrong user input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But that is a separate problem. `display()` is not running because nobody ever called it, be with invalid input or not.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, this should help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class CreatePurchase {
    static int invoiceNum; // I made these variables static because
    static double amount; // it fixed an error I was having with using
                            // non-static variables in a static field?

    static double tax = .05;
    static double totalAmount;

    public void updatePurchase(final Purchase purchase) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Please enter the invoice number! (Must be between 1000 and 8000!)");
        invoiceNum = input.nextInt();

        if (invoiceNum < 1000 || invoiceNum > 8000) {
            System.out
                    .println("The invoice number you entered is invalid, try again!");
            updatePurchase(purchase);

        }
        System.out
                .println("Please enter the amount of the sale! (Must be greater than 0!)");
        amount = input.nextDouble();

        if (amount < 0) {
            System.out.println("The sale amount is invalid, try again!");
            updatePurchase(purchase);
        }

        setTotalAmount(tax, amount);

        display(invoiceNum, amount, getTotalAmount());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Purchase completedPurchase = new Purchase();
        new CreatePurchase().updatePurchase(completedPurchase);
    }

    public int getInvoiceNum(int invoiceNum) {
        return invoiceNum;
    }

    public double getAmount(double amount) {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(double tax, double amount) {
        totalAmount = (amount * tax);
    }

    public void display(int invoiceNum, double amount, double totalAmount) {
        System.out.println("Your invoice number is:" + invoiceNum + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount is: " + amount + ".");
        System.out.println("Your sale amount after tax is: " + totalAmount
                + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for replying, it was helpful to see all the different ways I can make something work!